Can i remove wall bracing on the first level after i put my floor trusses on and sheet them?
I have a 64" poured icf and 57" framed walls on top of that everything is braced and the floor trusses are ready to be installed. I am wondering if after I put the trusses and sheathing them is it OK to remove the temporary wall bracing

I'm not sure what a "floor truss" is...

it's a long, low, flat-topped truss, used like a joist.
